# A message to ColleenV

Tags: support

I don't know if it is appropriate to post "any way thank you for your service message" here. But I hope this be not deleted.

I have been not here for a while, but there was time when I was quite active here and I (lol) always confronted with ColleenV if I look back ( am I correct?^^ ).

I, a probably one of the few Japanese here, but I was taught by many and also **you**, I here would like to present a thank you message for your service message whatever the cause was.

Thanks sincerely(m_m). ( And congratulation to new moderators.)

Regards.

Comment: You're welcome! :) That's a very nice gesture. There was a period of time when I spent so much time on the site, it was [hard to miss](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/you%20can't%20miss%20it "impossible not to see or notice") me.

Comment: @ColleenV Thank you from here too. Now as is in your country, Tokyo was hit by the coronavirus, the probably super insane government is "asking" social distancing, without very slow stimulus package which never comes to me(lol), killing people economically, so my last word to you you should stay away from Asia, or my country. Have a good future!